CI/CD testing.ERROR: Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::{closure}(): Argument #2($request) must be of type Request, Illuminate\Http\Request given
I am trying to run PHPUnit test in GitLab CICD with a GitLab Runner set up on a Windows PC. My test keeps on failing with the error below; I have looked around on the internet and found not so much help with regard to my issue. Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml as well; What I have already done includes setting up jobs for asset preparation and build for frontend assets with npm as I am running React with Typescript, bridging it with Inertiajs from the Laravel backend.
 
NB: This is a fresh install with the built-in or Laravel 11 shipped Test cases.

image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker:latest

stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - debug
  - syntax
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  DB_HOST: mysql
  APP_PREVIOUS_KEYS: $APP_KEY

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"

default:
  tags:
    - My-Windows-Runner

composer:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - echo "Running composer install..."
    - cp .env.example .env
    - echo "APP_KEY=$APP_KEY" >> .env
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --no-suggest
    - echo "Composer install completed."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
  cache:
    paths:
      - vendor/

npm:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - npm install @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps --pure-lockfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/

buildDevAssets:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - npm
  script:
    - echo "PUSHER_APP_KEY=$PUSHER_TEST_APP_KEY" >> .env
    - $env:LARAVEL_BYPASS_ENV_CHECK=1
    - npm run build --progress false
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public/build/
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
  except:
    - main

debugAssets:
  stage: debug
  script:
    - echo "Debugging assets..."
    - echo "Listing contents of public/build/"
    - Get-ChildItem -Path public/build/
  when: always
  dependencies:
    - buildDevAssets

phpCsFixer:
  stage: syntax
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php-cs-fixer.php --verbose --diff --dry-run

eslint:
  stage: syntax
  dependencies:
    - npm
  script:
    - npx eslint .
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

phpstan:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - composer php artisan
# In this job, set up the MacOS and Unix/Linux specific commands when each environment is available.
phpunit:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - composer
    - buildDevAssets
  script:
    - echo "Running PHPUnit..."
    - php -v
    - php artisan storage:link
    - echo "Creating .env.testing file..."
    - |
      echo "APP_ENV=testing" > .env.testing
      echo "APP_URL=http://localhost" >> .env.testing
      echo "DB_CONNECTION=sqlite" >> .env.testing
      echo "DB_DATABASE=./database/database.sqlite" >> .env.testing
      echo "CACHE_DRIVER=file" >> .env.testing
      echo "QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync" >> .env.testing
      echo "SESSION_DRIVER=file" >> .env.testing
      echo "LOG_CHANNEL=stderr" >> .env.testing
    - php artisan config:clear
    - php artisan key:generate --env=testing
    - echo "APP_PREVIOUS_KEYS=$APP_PREVIOUS_KEYS" >> .env.testing
    - echo "Creating SQLite database file..."
    - if (Test-Path database\database.sqlite) { Remove-Item database\database.sqlite }
    - New-Item -ItemType File -Path database\database.sqlite
    - echo "Clearing config cache..."
    - echo "Running migrations..."
    - php artisan migrate --env=testing --force
    - echo "Running PHPUnit..."
    - .\vendor\bin\phpunit --version
    - php -d short_open_tag=off .\vendor\bin\phpunit --colors=never --stderr --exclude-group integration
    - echo "PHPUnit completed."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_failure

And here below are the errors; After reading some of the not-so-closely related issues, I tried to set APP_URL to localhost in the .gitlab-ci.yml, but that did not still mitigate the issue!
.S.F.[2024-06-07 14:08:58] testing.ERROR: Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::{closure}(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Request, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\m-zBgUhn\0\path-to-my-laravel-project-on-gitlab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 676 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase::{closure}(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Request, Illuminate\\Http\\Request given, called in C:\\GitLab-Runner\\builds\\m-zBgUhn\\0\\path-to-my-laravel-project-on-gitlab\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php on line 676 at C:\\GitLab-Runner\\builds\\m-zBgUhn\\0\\path-to-my-laravel-project-on-gitlab\\bootstrap\\app.php:27)
[stacktrace]


Looks like a typehint issue, somewhere in your code you've defined a function argument as \Request instead of \Illuminate\Http\Request

Thank you that was it and it solved the issue. The culprit was in the bootstrap/app.php

Thank you that was it and it solved the issue. The culprit was in the bootstrap/app.php. Hey @ArunAS , why don't you post this as you answer, then I will mark it as the right one. Also kindly vote my question up, if you think it's a valuable addition to the platform!
